# PEGASUS pre-training for summarisation tasks

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, summarization, huggingface-tokenizers

I am unsure of how the evaluation for large document summarisation is conducted for the recently introduced [PEGASUS model](http://scholar.google.com.sg/scholar_url?url=http://proceedings.mlr.press/v119/zhang20ae/zhang20ae.pdf&hl=en&sa=X&ei=It5iYPzDPKuM6rQP-6OsuAc&scisig=AAGBfm3TMc7EP3WzoI9nibV1Z0HLzzeb2w&nossl=1&oi=scholarr) for single document summarisation.

The author's show evaluation against large document datasets like Big Patent, PubMed etc with document lengths exceeding that of the input size to the transformer models.

To quote from the paper, they did talk about this but didn't really elaborate further.

> CNN/DailyMail, Multi-News, arXiv, PubMed, BIG- PATENT datasets contain input documents longer than the maximum input length (`L_input = 512 tokens`) in pre- training. This would present a problem for position em- beddings which would never be updated for longer input lengths, but we confirm the postulation that sinusoidal po- sitional encodings (Vaswani et al., 2017) generalize well when fine-tuning PEGASUSLARGE beyond the input lengths observed in training up to `L_input = 1024 tokens`. Since average input length in BIGPATENT, arXiv, PubMed and Multi-News are well beyond 1024 tokens, further scaling up `L_input` or applying a two-stage approach (Liu et al., 2018) may improve performance even more, although this is out- side the scope of this work.

They did mention that the input length is up till 1024 tokens. In the PEGASUS Large model on huggingface the max input tokens is also 1024.

I am not sure how they managed to extend their document summarisations for more than 1024 tokens.

I would also like to do similar for my own long document summarisations that I want to try.